# Start MongoDB instance with SSL

Tags: mongodb, ssl

**I have my mongod.conf file as follows:**

```
 systemLog:
      destination: file
      logAppend: true
      path: /home/abc/mongoDB/log/mongod.log

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /home/abc/mongoDB/data/db
  journal:
    enabled: true

 processManagement:
  fork: true  
  pidFilePath: /home/abc/mongoDB/mongod.pid  

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27018
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1  
  ssl:
    mode: requireSSL
    PEMKeyFile: /home/abc/mongodb.pem
```

I have made sure the .pem file is located in the path i mentioned above.
I'm trying to run a instance of mongodb reading the .conf file with the following command:

```
mongod -f /home/abc/mongoDB/mongod.conf
```

It was working fine until i tried to include SSL but now i'm getting the following message:

```
[abc@abc ~]$ mongod -f /home/abc/mongoDB/mongod.conf
Unrecognized option: security.sslPEMKeyfile
try 'mongod --help' for more information
```

I created the .pem file with openssl as follows:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -out mongodb-cert.crt -keyout mongodb-cert.key
```

and then merged the files with :

```
cat mongodb-cert.key mongodb-cert.crt > mongodb.pem
```

Could anyone help what I did wrong here?
My approach was based on [this.](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following configuration worked form me:

```
net:
  port: 27018 
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1  # Listen to local interface only, comment to listen on all interfaces. 
  ssl:
      mode: requireSSL
      PEMKeyFile: /home/abc/mongodb.pem
      PEMKeyPassword: password
      CAFile: /home/abc/client.pem
```

more info [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/)